# Table view property in iphone

Tags: iphone

How to change the colour of text of each row in tableview in iphone? Anyone know about it? Then Please give me the guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you would need to do is the following in the `tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

```
cell.textLabel.textColor = yourColor;
```

If you want more info on using custom cells you can check out my blog [Effective Mobility](http://effectivemobility.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-custom-cells-in-your-uitableview.html)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Add:

```
  cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: I want different different colour on text of each row of tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Have your all row colours in an NSArray. Lets say myColorArray and it will contain all your UIColor objects for the rows.

And do `cell.textLabel.textColor = [myColorArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in

`tableView:CellForRowAtIndexPath:` function.