# Table view property in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table view property in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153227/table-view-property-in-iphone)

I want to put the different different color of text of each row in Tableview in iPhone.
How can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"my cell id";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (nil == cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];
    }
    //your custom init of a cell here
    ...
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } ...
    return cell;
}
```